# Why is my code not compiling when including OpenCV in my Visual Studio Project?

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

There is too much code to post so I'll be short and sweet here.
I'm migrating a project to Visual Studio that I originally built in Eclipse on OSX, using the OpenCV Apple framework distribution (opencv delivered as a .framework).

I've created a visual studio project from the existing code but when I build it, I get a bunch of errors from one of the headers (opencv2/core/fast_math.hpp) that are included along the header chain of `<opencv2/opencv.hpp>`.

```
1>c:\users\blah\tools\lib\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\fast_math.hpp(105):
error C2065: '__m128d': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\blah\tools\lib\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\fast_math.hpp(105):
error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 't'
1>c:\users\blah\tools\lib\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\fast_math.hpp(105):
error C2065: 't': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\blah\tools\lib\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\fast_math.hpp(105):
error C3861: '_mm_set_sd': identifier not found
1>c:\users\blah\tools\lib\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\fast_math.hpp(106):
error C2065: 't': undeclared identifier
```

Nothing has really changed in my code, just that I'm now using Visual Studio 2017.  I have added opencv\build\include to my include path.  I see that this code is SIMD intrinsics, which I don't think should have any problem compiling.

Is there a step I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be something with how I set up the project.  The SIMD intrinsics require extra headers.  I didn't configure the project to use precompiled headers which also appears to explain why std::string was undefined too.  The extra headers can be added in stdafx.h and it's presence resolves other missing components.